# Laravel Auth::guard('name') access table column directly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2
and i have created my custom guards for authentication like this

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
],
```

---

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'admin',
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

all login is working fine but if you remember the in previous version of laravel 4.2  we were able to access the user table column directly using 
`Auth::user()->get->id`  or `Auth::user()->id`

in Laravel 5.2 i am trying to do same like

`Auth::guard('admin')->get->email`  or `Auth::guard('admin')->get->id`  which throws an error.

may i know if its accessible like this on this version of laravel  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got the solution.
We will require to use

```
Auth::guard('admin')->user()->email
```

Answer (score 0):

In Providers array use model instead of table

```
 'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
 ]
```

and also in Admin model extend

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class Admin extends Authenticatable{
  ...
 }
```

Comment: Login works perfectly /. 
trying to access this `echo Auth::guard('admin')->get()->email;` still not working  :-(

Comment: To get email try  `Auth::guard('admin')->email`

Comment: It will work with Auth::guard('admin')->user()->email  :-)